# How to reduce the facebook sharing image size.?

Tags: facebook, drupal, sharing

I am using an image `1024*768`, But I cropped this to 200*200 by using

```
'property' => 'og:image:width',
```

But Its not getting cropped, in the facebook it is showing full width of the image. Is there any alternate ways to cropped image to display after sharing.? Thanks in advance.

 I am using addThis module in drupal.

Answer (score 0):

`og:image:width` is not a "cropping" property; it's purpose is to tell the scraper upfront about the *real* image dimensions.

If you want to use a 200px*200px image - then you have specify one as `og:image`.